# Implementing surrogate key in hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

Can we implement surrogate key and unique index for hive table?

I want to auto-increment the value of one of my column in hive table. And make another column a unique key which does not allow duplicate insertion into the hive table.

Answer (score 0):

Currently ticket in this regard is open-

[Auto Increment Key and constraints](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6905)